# More efficient way to get integer permutations?

Tags: python, integer, permutation, python-itertools

I can get integer permutations like this:

```
myInt = 123456789

l = itertools.permutations(str(myInt))
[int(''.join(x)) for x in l]
```

Is there a more efficient way to get **integer** permutations in Python, skipping the overhead of creating a string, then joining the generated tuples? Timing it, the tuple-joining process makes this 3x longer than  `list(l)`.

added supporting information

```
myInt =123456789
def v1(i): #timeit gives 258ms
    l = itertools.permutations(str(i))
    return [int(''.join(x)) for x in l]

def v2(i): #timeit gives 48ms
    l = itertools.permutations(str(i))
    return list(l)

def v3(i): #timeit gives 106 ms
    l = itertools.permutations(str(i))
    return [''.join(x) for x in l]
```

Comment: I clarified, longer than 'list(l)'

Comment: I took the liberty of posting some timeit results to help clarify OP's problem

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
>>> digits = [int(x) for x in str(123)]
>>> n_digits = len(digits)
>>> n_power = n_digits - 1
>>> permutations = itertools.permutations(digits)
>>> [sum(v * (10**(n_power - i)) for i, v in enumerate(item)) for item in permutations]
[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

This avoids conversion to and from a tuple as it'll use the integer's position in the tuple to compute its value (e.g., `(1,2,3)` means `100 + 20 + 3`).

Because the value of `n_digits` is known and the same throughout the process, I think you can also optimize the computations to:

```
>>> values = [v * (10**(n_power - i)) for i, v in enumerate(itertools.repeat(1, n_digits))]
>>> values
[100, 10, 1]
>>> [sum(v * index for v, index in zip(item, values)) for item in permutations]
[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

I also think we don't need to call `zip()` all the time because we don't need that list:

```
>>> positions = list(xrange(n_digits))
>>> [sum(item[x] * values[x] for x in positions) for item in permutations]
[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

Comment: And the first line being the same as `digits = [int(x) for x in str(123)]`

Comment: This does indeed work but I don't believe it is more efficient than v1 given above. Thank you!

Comment: @JumBopap: I have just added an optimization that I could think of. Have you timed it rather than believing it's not faster?

Comment: I did indeed time it, on my computer v1 = 0.452999830246 seconds and your first version is 1.46900010109 seconds and your second version is  1.35899996758 seconds.

Comment: @JumBopap: thanks, that's pretty clear. I have added another version that doesn't call `zip()` all the time. Not sure if it's much faster but if not, have you considered writing a small C module for this? You can then call that C function from Python.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on Simeon's answer, so I'm adding this here.

If you try to permute `120` with the function in the answer, you get

```
[120,102,210,201,12,21]
```

12 and 21 are wrong answers, so I made a modification to discard them:

```
def permute(n):
        digits = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
        n_digits = len(digits)
        n_power = n_digits - 1
        values = [v * (10**(n_power - i)) for i, v in
            enumerate(itertools.repeat(1, n_digits))]
        positions = list(range(n_digits))
        permutations = {sum(item[x] * values[x] for x in positions) for
            item in itertools.permutations(digits) if item[0] > 0}
        for p in permutations:
            yield p
```

Edit: also forgot to add that the function will count the same digits twice, leaving you with duplicates, so I modified that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators):

```
import itertools as it
gen = it.permutations(range(1, 10))
```

Then you can iterate over each item:

```
for i in gen:
    #some code
```

Or convert it to a list, but it'll take some time:

```
items = list(gen)
```

EDIT: Clarified that you want back an integer, maybe the fastest way is using another lazy evaluation:

```
gen = (int('%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d' % x) for x in it.permutations(range(1, 10)))
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing but his code is indeed much slower than calling list

Comment: In this process wouldn't I have to iterate through every integer in the generator, convert the integers to a string, then iterate again to join every tuple, then finally convert the joined-tuple back into ints?