# Number permutations in python iterative

Tags: python, permutation

I need to generate permutations of digits, the number can be bigger than the digit count. For my current purpose I need to generate permutations of these digits `0, 1, 2` to get numbers of upto 20 digits length. For example I the first few permutations would be `0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, ... 1122, 1211`.

There are existing answers using Iterator in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052951/python-get-all-combinations-of-numbers) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630147/more-efficient-way-to-get-integer-permutations) and those gives the full permutation directly.

But I need to perform some tests over each permutations and if I keep the entire permutations list in memory it becomes too big, especially for 20 digits it comes to 3<sup>20</sup> permutations.

So my question is can it be done without recursion, so that I can perform the tests over each permutations.

**Edit**:

I'm looking at **permutations with repetitions**. So for a number of say 20 digits, each digit can take value from `[0, 1, 2]`. That's why the number of permutations in that case will come to 3<sup>20</sup>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking is called a Cartesian product, not a permutation. Python itertools have a method [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce the desired result:

```
import itertools

for p in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=4):
    print p
```

Output is 3^4 lines:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
...
(2, 2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

To produce output tuples with length form 1 to 4, use an additional iteration:

```
for l in range(1, 5):
    for p in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=l):
        print p
```

Finally, this works for string elements, too:

```
for i in range(5):
    for p in itertools.product(('0', '1', '2'), repeat=i):
        print ''.join(p),
print
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22 000 001 002 010 [...] 2220 2221 2222
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great is generating the sequence. How can I a test function such as `def perform_test(pux):
        if pux%9==0:
        print "OK"` over each item on the resulting list?

Comment: @kaydee Thanks for up-vorting and accepting my answer, if it works for you. :)  Your test: `if int(pux) % 9 == 0: print pux, "OK"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your program could like like this:

```
import itertools


def perform_test(permutation):
    pass

# permutations() does not construct entire list, but yields 
# results one by on.
for permutation in itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    perform_test(permutation)
```

Comment: One problem with this is if I try to use a smaller `tuple` to get a larger permutations it doesn't work for me. Case in point `for pu in permutations([1, 2], 3):
    perform_test(pu)`  ; `def perform_test(pux):
    print pux`

Comment: Using the following function   `def perform_test(pux):
#    print pux
    if int(pux)%9==0:
        print "OK" ` throws an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: @kaydee "if I try to use a smaller tuple to get a larger permutations it doesn't work for me." - what result do you expect as permutations of three elements by two places?

Comment: e.g. 12101 it's generating elements are `[0, 1, 2]`, but if I do `permutations([0, 1, 2], 5)` it doesn't give me anything. Each digit of a, let's say 5 digit long number, can have any one digit from `[0, 1, 2]`. So it's a permutations with repetitions allowed. Hope that clears up.

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to do this using itertools etc, here is a way that is a bit different from what you would normally do.

If you were to have a list of these permutations in order, what you would actually have is ternary numbers that represent their place in the list. e.g. list[4] is 11 which is 4 in ternary (3*1+1*1). So you could convert the index value that you want to test into ternary and that would produce the correct value.

While python can do conversion from an integer to its form in that base (e.g. int("11",3) outputs 4) the reverse is not implicitly implemented. There are lots of implementations out there though. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063425/python-elegant-inverse-function-of-intstring-base) is a good one (modified for your case):

```
def digit_to_char(digit):
    if digit < 10:
        return str(digit)
    return chr(ord('a') + digit - 10)

def perm(number):
    (d, m) = divmod(number, 3)
    if d > 0:
        return perm(d) + digit_to_char(m)
    return digit_to_char(m)
```

So if you wanted to find the 20th permutation, you could do perm(20), which would give you 202. So now you can just do a regular loop through the index values that you want. With no storage of big lists in memory.

```
permutation = 0
i = 0
while len(str(permutation)) < 20:
    permutation = perm(i)
    do_test(permutation)
    i += 1
```